# How to show Html Content in Android Layout?

Tags: android, json, zend-framework

I have a php file which is containing the html markup like this

```
<h4>Standard Web Browser Components</h4>
<p>Let&#8217;s lay out a few components of the modern day web browser:</p>
<ul>
<li>Parsing (HTML, XML, CSS, JavaScript)</li>
<li>Layout</li>
<li>Text and graphics rendering</li>
<li>Image decoding</li>
<li>GPU interaction</li>
<li>Network access</li>
<li>Hardware acceleration</li>
</ul>
<header>
<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="/2012/chrome-canary-for-developers/">Chrome Canary for Developers</a></h1>
<p class="meta">
<time datetime="2012-11-02T08:16:00+04:00" pubdate data-updated="true">Nov 2<span>nd</span>, 2012</time>
</p>
</header>
```

I want to parse this in my Android layout. I did it like this way

```
webtext.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
```

but I am loosing the style and color of the content. How can I show in my layout without loosing the style.

Comment: there is no definition for your classes. You may be missing the style definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because only following tags are allowed for `Html.fromHtml()`

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

**Reference** http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

**PS :**

**to Load styles etc in WebView try following**

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebViewId);
String strHtml = "<html><head>"
          + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #ffdec2; background-color: #1F0C01;}"
          + "</style></head>"
          + "<body>"
          + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
          ....................
          ....................
          ....................
          + "</p> "
          + "</body></html>";

myWebView.loadData(strHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: so is there any other way to do that . 
So I will get the exact results like the webpage? (without using webview)